# Mongoose - FindOne and Save is not function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a new in `expressJs` and `mongoose` (include MongoDB).
The problem is when I'm trying to find a patient by with `findOne()`, the catch error says:

> model.findOne is not function.

I never has this error. 
Well my code with errors are:

```
var Paciente = require('../modelos/Paciente');
var pacienteSchema = Paciente.pacienteSchema;

/**
 * 
 * Metodo para añadir un nuevo paciente
 */
function nuevoPaciente(request, response) {
    var BODY = request.body;
    const rutNuevo = BODY.nuevoPaciente.Rut;
    var pacienteEntrada = new pacienteSchema(BODY.nuevoPaciente);
    try {
        console.log(pacienteEntrada);
        pacienteEntrada.findOne({
            Rut: rutNuevo
        }, (err, pacienteExiste) => {
            console.log(err);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, pacienteExiste);
                response.status(500).send({
                    msjError: 'Error interno al guardar el paciente',
                    numError: 1,
                    err
                });
            } else if (!pacienteExiste) {
                console.log("El paciente no existe, hay que guardarlo");
                pacienteEntrada.save((err, pacienteSave) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    if (err) {
                        response.status(500).send({
                            msjError: 'Error interno al guardar el paciente',
                            numError: 1,
                            err
                        });
                    } else if (!pacienteSave) {
                        response.status(404).send({
                            msjError: 'No se ha guardado el usuario',
                            numError: 3,
                            err
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(pacienteSave);
                        response.status(200).send({
                            msjError: 'El paciente se ha guardado con exito!',
                            numError: 0,

                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("paciente ya registrado");
                response.status(400).send({
                    msjError: 'El paciente ya existe registrado',
                    numError: 2,

                });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Problemas");
        console.log(err);

        response.status(500).send({
            msjError: 'Error no existen los parametros necesarios para guardar al nuevo paciente',
            err
        });
    }
}
```

The code Paciente is (`module.exports`):

```
module.exports = {
  //pacienteSchema: mongoose.model('Paciente', pacienteSchema),
  pacienteSchema: mongoose.model('Paciente', pacienteSchema),
  pacienteFormEnfermeria: pacienteFormEnfermeria,
  pacienteModelFormEnfermeria: pacienteModelFormEnfermeria,
  pacienteFormKinesiologia: pacienteFormKinesiologia,
  pacienteModelFormKinesiologia: pacienteModelFormKinesiologia,
  pacienteModelFormNutricion: pacienteModelFormNutricion,
  pacienteFormNutricion: pacienteFormNutricion,
  pacienteFormModalRegistro: pacienteFormModalRegistro,
  pacienteFormRegistro: pacienteFormRegistro
}
```

And the variable `pacienteSchema` is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var pacienteSchema = Schema({
      Nombre: String,
      ApellidoPaterno: String,
      ApellidoMaterno: String,
      Rut: String,
      Edad: Number,
      FechaNacimiento: Date,
      genero: String,
      Nacionalidad: String,
      Direccion: String,
      Comuna: String,
      telefonoContacto: String,
      celular: String,
      Prevision: String,
      patologiaConsulta: String,
      creenciasReligiosas: String,
      costumbres: String,
      etnia: String,
      estadoCivil: String,
      grupoFamiliar: String,
      hijos: String,
      redApoyo: String,
      escolaridad: String,
      ocupacion: String,
      horarioLaboral: String,
      diasFaltaTrabajo: Number,
      accidentesLaborales: String,
      riesgosLaborales: String,
      practicasDeportivas: String,
      hobbies: String,
      estadoVivienda: String,
      accesoServiciosBasicos: String,
      antecedentesFamiliares: String});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `pacienteSchema.findOne`, not the instantiated `pacienteEntrada` which represents *a document* (like a row in relational DBs). Whereas `pacienteSchema` represents the access to *the collection of documents* (like a table in relational DBs).

And by the way, `Paciente.pacienteSchema` should be called something like `Paciente.pacienteModel` instead (since it's a value returned by `mongoose.model`).

`pacienteEntrada.save` should be OK already, however your callback seems wrong: I believe it will be called with only one (error) argument, so your second argument (`pacienteSave`) must be `undefined`. Which makes your function send a 404 and look like it failed.

Either these, or you connected your DB with `mongoose.createConnection` instead of `mongoose.connect` (in which case you need to use the returned connection instead of `mongoose` directly - check [their doc](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose#connecting-to-mongodb) and [the warning](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose#accessing-a-model) about accessing a model on a separate connection).

Comment: oh! you are right, pacienteSchema is the one wich represents the access to the collection. I was confused with this terms pacienteEntrada/pacienteSchema.